# Obtener datos de formulario por ajax - metodo POST funciono - metodo PUT no

Tags: ajax, laravel, formularios

Tengo un formulario que me envia la informacion al controlador por ajax.

Al agregar un registro usando type: POST si funciona ya que al hacer dd($request->all()) me muestra el array con los datos.

```
function saveReg() {
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('Date', $('#Date').val());
    datos.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{url('/emp/newReg')}}',
        data: datos,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // location.reload();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            showAjaxErrors(data, 'error_msg');
            markError(['Date', 'file']);
        }
    });
```

Pero usando metodo PUT no me envia la informacion al control ya que al hacer dd($request->all()) me muestra el array en blanco

```
function saveReg() {
var datos = new FormData();
datos.append('Date', $('#Date').val());
datos.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: '{{url('/emp/newReg')}}',
    data: datos,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        // location.reload();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        showAjaxErrors(data, 'error_msg');
        markError(['Date', 'file']);
    }
});
```

Comment: podrias publicar tus ROUTES ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La documentación de AJAX dice:

*El tipo de solicitud a realizar ("POST" o "GET"); el valor predeterminado es "GET". Nota: otros métodos de solicitud HTTP, como PUT y DELETE, también se pueden usar aquí, pero no son compatibles con todos los navegadores.*

Lo que te recomiendo es utilizar GET y POST, ya que todo se puede hacer con esos 2 métodos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero `PUT` es para url especificas:
si queremos crear un usuario ejemplo:
la url de la solicitud debe ser especificamente para el elemento
http://example/user/newuser
mientras que para `POST` 
puede ser simplemente
 http://example/user/ 
ya que `POST` enviara los datos al servidor unicamente y ya en el server se decide que hacer con ellos:

1. `PUT` pone un recurso en la dirección especificada en la URL.
   Exactamente en esa dirección. Si no existe, lo crea, si existe lo
   reemplaza.
2. `POST` envía datos a una URL para que el recurso en esa URI los
   maneje.

y las diferencias mas grandes:

```
Una petición PUT a una URL afecta únicamente a esa URL. Un POST a una URL puede tener cualquier efecto.
En una petición PUT, los datos incluidos en el cuerpo de la petición se toman como una entidad que quedará accesible en la dirección URL de la petición.
Solo debemos utilizar PUT cuando sabemos exactamente la url correspondiente al recurso que vamos a crear (o actualizar).
PUT es idempotente, POST no es idempotente.
```

ahora bien una vez entendido esto vamos a laravel con un ejemplo simple:

```
<form action="{{ route('route_name') }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

esto producira este resultado:

```
<form action="{{ route('route_name') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

como vez no existe un metedo put... se envie un metodo post con un input hidden con name _method y value put

**ahora con jquery:**
aunque existe los metodos `PUT` y `DELETE` no son compatibles con todos los navegadores